# undefined local variable or method for #<RSpec + Rspec 3.5

Tags: rspec

Stackers,

I am stuck on an error that I keep getting when running this spec in RSPEC. I am using:

> rspec-core (3.5.3)
>         rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
>       rspec-expectations (3.5.0)

Now here is the spec that I am using:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Service, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(service).to be_valid
  end
end
```

This is the factory with factory girl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :service do
    name        { Faker::Lorem.word }
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(5) }
  end
end
```

I have a service model "service.rb" and the content is rather simple:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

And finally this is the error that I keep getting:

> ```
> Failures:
>
>   1) Service has a valid factory
>      Failure/Error: expect(service).to be_valid
>
>      NameError:
>        undefined local variable or method `service' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Service:0x007fa4ba80bea0>
>      # ./spec/models/service_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
> Finished in 0.02976 seconds (files took 1.52 seconds to load)
> 1 example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/service_spec.rb:4 # Service has a valid factory
> ```

Comment: Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You souldn't test that "Service has a valid factory", that way you are testing the test (?). Just add tests for the model functionality and the service factory will be valid as a necesity for all the tests to pass, you don't need to test your test configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, something like below you will have to write. You need to initialize a service instance via Factory to use in the spec file.

```
 RSpec.describe Service, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    service = FactoryGirl.create :service
    expect(service).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Better approach is building factory instance outside the context and using the same instance in multiple tests.

```
describe 'validate factory' do
  let(:factory) { FactoryGirl.create :service }
  it 'sets the type_id field' do
    expect(service).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: That did the trick, for those of you using this Tutorial (https://www.sitepoint.com/learn-the-first-best-practices-for-rails-and-rspec/) please note this asnwer it will work.

Comment: @user2164689 - Please accept the answer if that solved your problem.

Comment: Use FactoryGirl.build instead of FactoryGirl.create to test validations, it's faster because it does not write to the database and you don't need a persisted record to test validations.